# Get user active posts randomly

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users

I am having an array of product ID

```
$products_ids = array(183,185,101);
```

I am having list of user IDs

```
$user_ids= array(142,234,236);
```

I want to get a single post by an user randomly but i have to check if the user( by ID) has brought any of the product ( by ID).

This is the function to check if user has purchased product:

```
wc_customer_bought_product( $user_id, $product_id );
```

But i can't pass an array to it.I have a solution for getting the post randomly if am able to remove array elements form $user_ids by checking with product ids.

```
$current_user_posts = get_posts( [
    'author__in'    =>  $authors, 
    'orderby'       =>  'random',
    'post_per_page' => '1',
    'order'         =>  'ASC' 
] );
```

What method should i adopt to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer which show how you could fill the `$authors` array with the proper user IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i can't pass an array to it.I have a solution for getting the post
>   randomly if am able to remove array elements form $user_ids by
>   checking with product ids.

Yes, the `wc_customer_bought_product()` function only accepts a single user/product ID.

But you can loop through the `$user_ids` array, and for each user (ID), loop through the `$product_ids` and then call the `wc_customer_bought_product()` function, like this:

```
$authors = array();
foreach ( $user_ids as $user_id ) {
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        // User alread checked.
        if ( in_array( $user_id, $authors ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( '', $user_id, $product_id ) ) {
            $authors[] = $user_id;
        }
    }
}
var_dump( $authors ); // testing
```

### Additional Note

The [`wc_customer_bought_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_customer_bought_product.html) accepts three parameters:

```
wc_customer_bought_product( $customer_email, $user_id, $product_id );
```

Where you can provide only the `$customer_email` or `$user_id`, or both.

Also, `wc_customer_bought_product()` returns `true` only for orders that are **complete** and *not* on hold, processing, etc.